# integration tests startup really slow

Tags: grails

I am using grails 1.3.7, when running integration tests, i see below message before the tests start.

```
[copy] Copying 1 file to C:\Users\<USER_NAME>\.grails\1.3.7\projects\<PROJECT_NAME>
```

And this step takes a lot of time, sometime around 5 minutes. (I have i7 with 8 gigs and a comparatively decent HDD)

I see no big file in this directory, all are folders. What's going on here, which file is it trying to copy.

Is there any way to make it faster.

Comment: Is normal porject startup slow, too? I seems to me taht it's not copying of the file which slows you down... Do you have a dependency to a snapshot-version of a plugin/ressource? This would result in downloading this ressource with each project start. One workaround would be to use `grails interactive` to start grails only once for starting the tests several times...

Comment: Normal project startup is not that slow, and yes, I am already using grails interactive console